# Отделять ли вводное в начале присоединения после тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от тех заявителей, которые проходили дополнительную проверку – например, в случае если они посещали регионы, контролируемые террористическими организациями.

1 Наверное, здесь надо закрыть придаточное запятой?

2. Что такое часть после тире: присоединительная конструкция? Но по правилу о вводном слове в начале обособленного оборота, в частности присоединения, оно никаким знаком препинания от оборота не отделяется.

Выходит, что приведенном предложении знаки правильнее будет расставить так:

Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от тех заявителей, которые проходили дополнительную проверку, – например в случае если они посещали регионы, контролируемые террористическими организациями.

Comment: Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от тех заявителей, которые проходили дополнительную проверку, например в случае если они посещали регионы, контролируемые террористическими организациями. 

Так будет правильно?

Comment: На мой взгляд, да. Но первый случай также возможен как авторская пунктуация.

Answer (score 1):

*Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от тех заявителей,  которые проходили дополнительную проверку, – например в случае если они посещали регионы, контролируемые террористическими организациями.*

Другие варианты оформления:

*Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от тех заявителей,  которые проходили дополнительную проверку, – например  если они посещали регионы, контролируемые террористическими организациями.*  Это наиболее предпочтительный вариант, так как присоединение желательно **выделить** дополнительной паузой.

*Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от тех заявителей,  которые проходили дополнительную проверку, например если они посещали регионы, контролируемые террористическими организациями.*  Этот вариант проще в оформлении, но читается он хуже.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Это СПП с двумя придаточными, причем второе придаточное является присоединительным.

Запятая ставится после первого придаточного, тире обозначает присоединительную конструкцию. Постановка знаков препинания **независимая**: второе придаточное присоединяется к СПП, а не к первому придаточному.

Вводное слово ***например*** не обособляется на границе предложений (используется  как присоединительное слово).

Сложный союз ***в случае если*** допускается расчленять, но в данном случае это нежелательно ввиду распространенности предложения (запятых и так достаточно).

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

Если у нас СПП с двумя придаточными и последовательным подчинением, то второе придаточное всегда будет относиться к первому придаточному (оно для него будет главным).

Обычно в В СПП между предложениями  ставится **запятая**.

Можно ли поставить **тире**, чтобы обозначить **присоединение**? Вопрос дискуссионный (в правилах вроде бы не рассматривается), но в любом случае только тире вместо запятой можно поставить в предложении с **одним придаточным**, например:

*Эти заявители должны в некоторых случаях проходить дополнительную проверку – например если они посещали регионы...*

*Эти заявители должны в некоторых случаях проходить дополнительную проверку, например если они посещали регионы...*

Это два присоединительных варианта: с запятой и с тире.

Но если у нас **два придаточных**, то присоединенное придаточное должно относиться ко всему СПП, а не к другому придаточному, и тогда ставится **запятая и тире**.

*Данные о своих соцсетях требовали только от  заявителей,  которые проходили дополнительную проверку, – например  если они посещали регионы...*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (о расчленении союза ***в случае если***)

Союз является сложным и расчленяется при определенных условиях. Расчленению союза способствует наличие частиц и вводных слов перед союзом.

В то же время слово *например* от обычного союза запятой не отделяется (по правилу Розенталя), здесь вводное слово становится присоединительным (его функция меняется).

Поэтому можно считать, что расчленение допускается, но не является обязательным (вопрос дискуссионный).

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_122

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Answer (score 0):

Опять... Опять люди путаются при определении границ придаточной части.

Нет, запятая не требуется ни перед вводной конструкцией, ни **на основании** "конца" придаточной части.

Давайте разбираться:

*Заявители, которые проходили дополнительную проверку, например **из-за** посещения регионов, контролируемых террористическими организациями*.

Здесь я намеренно перестроил предложение для большего понимания. Весь приведенный фрагмент является **одной придаточной частью**, если рассматривать его в рамках цельного предложения. Теперь поймём, что же Вас смутило. Сочетание "например из-за посещения регионов* является не чем иным, кроме обособленного обстоятельства, поэтому отделяется запятой. Также отмечу, что при таких конструкциях вводные слова не отделяются запятой и принадлежат им же.

Кстати, пропуск запятой: **В случае (,) если...**

Comment: Привет! Попробую догадаться, почему Вам поставили минус. Ответ желательно начинать с  того варианта предложения, которое Вы считаете правильным. Потом  перейти к объяснению сомнительных знаков с учетом заданных вопросов и в соответствии с существующими правилами (по возможности). Желательно не отклоняться от темы (в разные стороны, туда-сюда) и не выражать эмоции без особых на то причин. Иначе ответ получается сумбурным, хаотичным. Я попробовала понять суть Ваших рассуждений, но у меня ничего не получилось. А ведь мне хотелось поставить Вам плюсик...

Comment: За подразумевающийся ключик всё равно спасибо, но печально, что меня мало кто понимает.